# How to use a dim as a file name inside workbooks() formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will copy a range from one open sheet (Original.xlsx) to another open sheet (Destination.xlsx). The tricky part is I want the user to be able to name the origin excel filename (without the .xlsx at the end) via inputbox and I am having trouble with combining the dim with the copy function.

```
Dim wbdest As Workbook
Dim X As Variant
X = InputBox("Workbook from name?")
Set wbdest = Workbooks(X & ".xlsx")

Workbooks("wbdest").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").copy
Workbooks("destination.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

The input box in this example will be input with "Original"

I am getting a Runtime error 9, subscript out of range on

```
Workbooks("wbdest").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").copy
```

Comment: Try `wbdest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Workbooks("wbdest").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").copy
```

with:

```
wbdest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").copy
```

*(there may be other errors in your posted code)*

Answer (score 0):

Your be best of doing it like this;

```
    Sub test()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook 'declare the workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook 'declare the workbook
    Dim strFile As String
        strFile = InputBox("Workbook from name?") 'open up input box for user to type in what workbook they want to copy

    Set wb1 = Workbooks(strFile & ".xlsx") 'set the user defined workbook by name
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Destination.xlsx") 'set the destination workbook by name

    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").Value = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:K25").Value 'put the value from userdefined workbook into destination

    End Sub
```

Try and avoid copy and pasting if you can :)